# Convert Tuple Type to Array of Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to replicate Angular's behavior of dependency injection in vanilla typescript.  My approach is to get the constructor's parameters' types as a tuple type, convert that into an array of types, then look into a dictionary object or array and get the object from that structure where its type matches the type in the array position.

In the code below, I've defined a test class where the constructor takes an apple and orange.  Below the class definition, I can get the types of each parameter into a tuple type called "TestClassParameters".

Is there any way I can convert this type : [apple,orange] into an array object => [typeof apple,typeof orrange]?

```
class Apple {}
class Orange { }

class TestClass {

    private apple : Apple;
    private orange: Orange;

    constructor(private apple: Apple, private orange: Orange) {}
}

type TestClassParameters = ConstructorParameters<typeof TestClass>;
```

Comment: You can't convert a type into a runtime object, since types are [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) in the compiled JavaScript.  TypeScript compiles to JavaScript; what approach would you take in pure JavaScript to get such dependency injection?  Once you figure that out, we can advise how to give that code some type safety.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a good point, I'd failed to realize that since this is design-time only, the dynamic approach cannot work since types will be erased before that point.  I'll need to re-evaluate.  I am hoping to still be able to do this by evaluating the constructor in some fashion, similar to Angular.

Comment: Where are you using this array?  If it's in the constructor, you could do `arguments.map(a => a.constructor)`.  Assuming that your calling function passes in an Apple and an Orange, this will create the array `[Apple, Orange]`.

Comment: That is close to what I am trying to achieve, in that it does give me strings corresponding to the type names.  However, since it is within the constructor, I will need to wait until an instance is instantiated, but I actually need this information to instantiate the instance.